# IPN suddenly not sending 'transaction_subject' field

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My IPN implementation has been untouched for about four years and has worked perfectly in all that time. But last week for some reason I don't appear to be receiving the 'transaction_subject' field value in by IPN callbacks. Has anyone else experienced this or have any idea why this has happened?

*Edit: Below is the IPN post that I received, as requested by* PayPal_Patrick

```
transaction_subject=
payment_date=21:49:54 Jul 28, 2013 PDT
txn_type=web_accept
last_name=REMOVED
residence_country=CA
item_name=REMOVED
payment_gross=
mc_currency=EUR
business=REMOVED
payment_type=instant
protection_eligibility=Ineligible
verify_sign=ARriB6IyMnFnOvenXyPlH5ooAOIEApSrdcUfoH0hyHiEqIC3.Gi5ojme
payer_status=verified
tax=0.00
payer_email=REMOVED
txn_id=67U74048Y42181247
quantity=1
receiver_email=REMOVED
first_name=REMOVED
payer_id=DHYR5X5ZHELCS
receiver_id=WAABZ68SWASH6
item_number=dbe8ee8e-6074-4e00-92ff-8d2f6f4bc329
handling_amount=0.00
payment_status=Completed
payment_fee=
mc_fee=0.78
shipping=0.00
mc_gross=10.95
custom=
charset=windows-1252
notify_version=3.7
ipn_track_id=75aecc60512bd
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample IPN post you're receiving that's missing the information?

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick - I've added this to the question now. The transaction_subject parameter is there but its value is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a system issue causing the problem. I'd suggest creating a ticket - here: PayPal.com/mts - and adding a comment to this thread with the ticket number.

Comment: @Mr. Flibble: If you've created a ticket there, please let us know. Especially if you've received an answer there that might be helpful for me and others here as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. The transaction_subject value simply started to be empty on July 24th (it worked the day before) after having worked without any problems for several years.
What did PayPal change that day?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact same problem! Very annoying. I was using the transaction_subject as a way of determining if it was a billable shopping cart transaction or not. Consequently this vanishing messed up my billing on a company I work for. Very bad.

There is a solution however!

The 'txn_type' field appears to be working well and not to have had issues. I looked back through IPN logs to spot it and check it's past behaviour. I've adjusted my system to use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

This issue started randomly occurring for one of our client websites. We never did work out why paypal stopped sending back this information but we did notice the same information was accessible via the "custom" field sent back.